# Big Query string to date

Tags: date, datetime, google-bigquery

How can I convert string to date by using `parse_timestamp` in Big Query?

```
"2022-12-12T14:17:41.9626+03:00"
```

I need something like following;

```
date(timestamp(parse_datetime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ", receivedAt)))
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems already [TIMESTAMP literals](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical#timestamp_literals), so you might consider below.

```sql
WITH sample_table AS (
  SELECT "2022-12-12T14:17:41.9626+03:00" received_at
)
SELECT EXTRACT(DATE FROM TIMESTAMP(received_at)) received_dt,
       PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%FT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez', received_at) received_at
  FROM sample_table;
```

**Query results**

[image]

- `%E*S` : Seconds with full fractional precision (a literal '*').
- `%Ez` : RFC 3339-compatible numeric time zone (+HH:MM or -HH:MM).

Comment: even date(timestamp(received_at)) will work here as the parsed entity will be a valid BQ timestamp.

Comment: Thank you all. But I want to learn how to parse .xxxx+03:00 part. I googled but I could not find anything. I know that extract will work.

Comment: @BenguAtici, kindly check out the updated answer if you are interested in format string.